# powerBI lookup and substrings

Tags: powerbi, lookup

I am looking for a DAX function, or any trick with pbi desktop, to do the operation below :

2 tables :

- 'data' table, with a data column in text format

eg: "Product XXX.YYY"

- 'ref' table, with 2 columnes, key and label. The keys are usually some substrings of the data fieds.

eg. "Product XXX"; "Label 1"

I need to add to the data table a measure that contains the label matching the first key from the ref table that is a substring of the data

eg : "Product XXX" is a substring of "Product XXX.YYY" => should return "Label 1"

Of course, all values on the data column have a diferent format, so I can not manipulate the data to split "Product XXX" and "YYY" in a static way.

thanks a lot !

Alternative : rather than a dummy substring, if the key could be a full regex pattern to be matched, would be far more interesting ... :)

Comment: It seems the issue lies in isolating`Product XXX` from the full string `Product XXX.YYY`. Could you add some example data as text?

Answer (score 0):

Without example data it's hard to test if this solution works, but since October 2018 there is a [fuzzy matching preview feature](http://radacad.com/fuzzy-matching-in-power-bi-and-power-query-match-based-on-similarity-threshold).

## Steps summary

1. Enable the fuzzy merge preview feature via File → Options → Preview Features
2. Go to Edit Queries and click on Merge Queries as New
3. Select the data table (containing the `Product XXX.YYY` values) as the source
4. Select the ref table as the match table
5. Pick a join type from the drop down
6. Tick the fuzzy matching checkbox
7. Try out some fuzzy matching options to see what is suitable